# Amazon Appstore reports "payment issue" when I try to update an app I bought a while ago

Tags: amazon-appstore

I remember having this issue months, possibly years ago. The error message is poorly worded and I forget what I did to resolve it last time...

http://note.io/1818dqP

Clicking the link takes me to a page (in the browser) that says that the digital orders page has moved, with a link to the new location. Following that link just shows me my order history and the "pending orders" that the app alludes to don't seem to be available anywhere.

My only thought for a resolution was that maybe it was looking at one of the expired credit cards I lazily hadn't removed from my account yet. I removed all expired cards, and I still have the issue.

What's most frustrating is that this is an app ***update***. It should be completely free.

Anyone got any ideas?